# Import SQL commands in a file from other file

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle 12c
I have multiple SQL files, which I separated as the file became very large.I have 2 files `First.sql` and `Second.sql`. I want to create a new file `Main.sql`, so that I can run the both the files together with same import.

How can we import the query of `First.sql` and `Second.sql` files into `Main.sql`

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using.

Comment: What tool are you using?  If you're using `SQL*Plus`, it would be as simple as having a main.sql that just `@first.sql @second.sql`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are running these scripts with sqlplus:

Contents of main.sql:

```
prompt Executing main.sql
@first.sql
@second.sql
prompt exiting main.sql
```

Contents of first.sql

```
prompt Executing first.sql
select sysdate from dual;
prompt Finished first.sql
```

Contents of second.sql

```
prompt Executing second.sql
select sysdate from dual;
prompt Finished second.sql
```

Executing main.sql

```
oracle:cdb$ sqlplus scott/tiger@pdb01

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Apr 11 08:29:11 2021
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Sun Apr 11 2021 08:26:21 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> @main.sql
Executing main.sql
Executing first.sql

SYSDATE
---------
11-APR-21

Finished first.sql
Executing second.sql

SYSDATE
---------
11-APR-21

Finished second.sql
exiting main.sql
SQL>
```